# cast as decimal/numeric syntax parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning how to correctly convert integers to decimal or numeric

If I want to have output that reads:

```
total
20.04
```

Query:

```
CAST(SUM(parts) AS NUMERIC(10,4)) as total

CAST(SUM(parts) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) as total
```

what do the 10, 4 or 12, 2 represent as the parameters for numeric and decimal?

Also when doing `CAST(SUM(sparts) AS FLOAT)` why are those parameters not needed?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL reference docs will give you good explanations of "fixed point" data-types v. "floating-point" data-types. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-types.html.  In essence, when you define a "fixed-point" data-type, the first digit (ie. the 10 or 12 in your example) indicates the total maximum number of digits that can be stored, and the second digit (ie. the 4 or 2 in your example) indicates the number of digits after the decimal point.  "Floating-point" data-types do not have a static number of digits defined

Comment: thanks so in the case of my output, does it really matter if I have 6, or 8 or 10 or 12 as the first parameter?

Comment: it matters to the extent that what you declare should be sufficient to hold the largest value that you expect to convert to.  For example, if you declared NUMERIC(6,4) then the largest possible value is 99.9999 (six digits in total, 4 digits after the decimal point).  If you expect the SUM of "parts" to be greater than 99.9999, then you need to convert (ie. CAST) to a data-type that is declared large enough to cater for the maximum possible value that you expect